# insert data from one table to another in sql which already do not exist

Tags: sql, insert, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table xx_photo in which i have to insert data from xx_people_ph table.

```
xx_photo :

IMAGE_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(15)   
PARENT_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(15)   
TABLE_NAME NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
IMAGE      NOT NULL BLOB         
DATA_FLAG           VARCHAR2(2)  
HIST_DATE           DATE
```

where whenever we insert data into xx_photo the hist_date will be updated to sysdate and data_flag to 'Y'.

xx_people_ph

```
IMAGE_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(15)   
PARENT_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(15)   
TABLE_NAME NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
IMAGE      NOT NULL BLOB
```

right now i am using :

```
insert into xx_photo
SELECT IMAGE_ID ,
  PARENT_ID ,
  Table_Name ,
  Image ,
  'Y',
  Sysdate
FROM Per_Images Img_Tab;

In this statement only , i want to check if the record for same parent_id exists
```

in xx_photo. If it already exists then the data should not be inserted in this table.

How can i modify this query to insert only those records which already do not exist in the xx_photo table

Comment: What is the unique combination to find the existence

Comment: What does parent_id relate to xx_people_ph image_id?  If it doesn't exist what do you want to happen, just not insert a record throw an error, insert it for you?  If you just want to stop if from inserting if parent doesn't exist, one way is to use an INNER JOIN to see if it exists

Comment: both parent_id is a unique id in both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Not Exists`

```
INSERT INTO xx_photo (Col1,col2,...)
SELECT image_id, 
       parent_id, 
       table_name, 
       image, 
       'Y', 
       sysdate 
FROM   per_images Img_Tab 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   xx_photo x 
                   WHERE  x.parent_id = Img_Tab.parent_id)
```

Comment: Thanks !! Perfect !